# How to successfully run Hangfire MemoryStorage jobs in console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, hangfire

I'm struggling with starting Hangfire jobs on simple C# console application using MemoryStorage. I wanted to try some things with Hangfire, but I just can't figure out how to configure it.

Here is my code:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();

        Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("fire!"));
        Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("minute!"), Cron.Minutely);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I'm not getting any of these messages.

I also tried using `JobStorage.Current = new MemoryStorage(new MemoryStorageOptions());`, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in-memory storage is used, you have to add Hangfire Server (i.e. a worker thread pool) to the same process which declares the storage (the storage is just a `ConcurrentDictionary` instance).

In a console app it could look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Easy!"));

    using (new BackgroundJobServer())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press ENTER to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I didn't realize the program has to be stopped there. The recurring job works as well.